# JOIN different tables depending on condition

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join, inner-join

There is a table of chat participants, `data_chats_parties`. In this table, there are two fields, `team` and `member` which denote if the participant is a member or team account. If team=0 then it is a member account. If team!=0 it is a team account.

If it is a team account, I need to fetch the `name` column from the `data_teams` table. Otherwise, I need to fetch the `username` column from the `data_members` table.

Obviously this query does not work, but it's what I'm trying to achieve.

```
SELECT data_chats_parties.*,data_teams.name,data_members.username
FROM data_chats_parties
  IF ( data_chats_parties.team!=0 THEN
    INNER JOIN data_teams ON data_teams.id=data_chats_parties.team ELSE
    INNER JOIN data_members ON data_members.id=data_chats_parties.member )
WHERE data_chats_parties.member!=1
GROUP BY data_chats_parties.id
```

The `WHERE data_chats_parties.member!=1` line just says "fetch participants who are not me".

Is it possible to achieve this in this manner?

Comment: Do separate queries for each join, and combine them with `UNION`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use 2 different queries and the perform a `UNION ALL`:

```sql
-- Get teams
SELECT
    dcp.*, dt.name
FROM data_chats_parties dcp
INNER JOIN data_teams dt
    ON dt.id = dt.team
WHERE
    dcp.member <> 1
    AND dcp.team <> 0

UNION ALL

-- Get members
SELECT
    dcp.*, dt.name
FROM data_chats_parties dcp
INNER JOIN data_members dm
    ON dt.id = dt.member
WHERE
    dcp.member <> 1
    AND dcp.team = 0
```